# where should we use GDALAllRegister() when implementing a class

Tags: mfc, gdal

I'm implementing a class named FilesWorkFlow. It's task is to open a file dialog and then if the file's extention is geotiff, some other member functions will be implemented to work with it. As you know before working with GDAL files , you have to call [`GDALAllRegister()`](https://gdal.org/api/index.html#raster-api#a9d40bc998bd6ed07ccde96028e85ae26) so I need to call this function somewhere in the class that all of the member functions will suppose GDAL drivers as registered. Where should I call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [`GDALAllRegister`](https://gdal.org/api/index.html#raster-api#a9d40bc998bd6ed07ccde96028e85ae26) states:

> This function should generally be called once at the beginning of the application.

Given that requirement I assume there's nothing wrong with calling it from your [`CWinApp::InitInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ae6yx0z0%28v=vs.140%29) override.

As an alternative you can encapsulate the GDAL functionality into a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) and use [Lazy Initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization).